# message: uninitialized constant Test (NameError) stops 'rails c' from working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails and have been following the steps to create a blog on a youtube tutorial. Everything was going fine till issuing the command `rail console` when this pops up and the command doesn’t initialise.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/test_case.rb:12:in `<module:ActiveSupport>':     uninitialized constant Test (NameError)
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/test_case.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:312:in `initialize_console'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'    


Rails -v = rails 3.2.16
Ruby -v = ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [i686-linux] ubuntu
RVM -v = rvm 1.26.7 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

There seems to be a few people with similar issues and I've tried to resolve it that way but it's been like 5 hours now and still no console.

There was a method that involved editing the `test_case.rb` by inserting `test/unit` in the requirements. The ruby file is readonly and won't even edit using the `gksudo edit test_case.rb`

Also there was info about it being due to not having `minitest` installed and in the `Gemfile`. Its definitely installed but I don't know how to put it in the `Gemfile`.

Can someone please, please help me.... I'm begging you.

Comment: try `sudo gedit filename.rb`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I have managed to edit the text in test_case.rb and then ran rails console command and now minitest is showing as uninitialized class variable. MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:328:in `autorun':@@installed_at_exit in Test::Unit::Runner (NameError)